# vim leaves the ouput after quitting

Tags: vim, shell, zsh

everytime I use vim, it leaves the output of the last file in the terminal. This didn't use to happen before. It used to clean up all the buffer. for example, the current behavior is

/Users/snihalani at 12:29PM 
➜ vim temp

1

~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
temp

/Users/snihalani at 12:29PM 
➜`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour of restoring the old text content (old screen) is called `alternate screen`.

In vim you can change this feature by adding the relevant lines to your .vimrc:
Which would be something like `set t_ti= t_te=`

You can also set it in a non-program specific (general) way by editing your terminfo and by setting the right terminal type. I do not have any experience with this, but [this page](http://www.shallowsky.com/linux/noaltscreen.html) seems to have clear descriptions. And with the term alternate screen known it is easy to google for more information. An alternative to search for is `smcup/rmcup`